# Need help summing/grouping values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I don't know if I should be doing this in SQL or not. It's part of an SSIS package, so maybe I should be using a script task, but before I go that route I'd like to know for sure that's required.

I have a fiddle setup - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f2aec/5.

Here is my data:

```
create table test (
    id int IDENTITY (1,1),
    account int,
    amount decimal(9,2),
    code varchar(10)
);

insert into test (account, amount, code)
values 
      (0, 100, 'A')
      ,(0, 100, 'B')

      ,(1, 100, 'A')
      ,(1, -50, 'B')
      
      ,(2, 100, 'A')
      ,(2, 200, 'B')
      ,(2, -100, 'C')
      
      ,(3, 100, 'A')
      ,(3, -200, 'B')
      ,(3, 50, 'C')
      
      ,(4, -500, 'B')
      ,(4, -500, 'C')
      
      ,(5, -1200, 'B')
      ,(5, 1000, 'C')
      
      ,(6, 150, 'A')
      ,(6, -100, 'B')
      ,(6, 200, 'C')
      
      ,(7, 150, 'A')
      ,(7, 200, 'B')
      ,(7, -100, 'C')
      
      ,(8, 550, 'A')
      ,(8, -700, 'B')
      ,(8, 300, 'C')
      ,(8, -100, 'D');
```

Here is my desired output:

```
-- desired output
-- 0 100.00 A
-- 0 100.00 B
-- 1 50.00 A
-- 2 200.00 B
-- 3 -50.00 A
-- 4 -500.00 B
-- 4 -500.00 C
-- 5 -200.00 B
-- 6 50.00 A
-- 6 200.00 B (currently wrong)
-- 7 50.00 A
-- 7 200.00 B (currently wrong)
-- 8 50.00 C (right now this is showing as C, but I would be okay if it was A)
```

Basically, if all records for an account are positive then I should show all records, same if all are negative, but if there is a mix I want to net the values and put them in the first code bucket.

Here is what I've tried so far (though I've been spinning my wheels so a completely fresh approach might be best).

```
;with cte as (
    select *
        ,sum(amount) over (PARTITION by account) as accounttotal
        ,sum(amount) over (PARTITION by account order by case when amount < 0 then 0 else 1 end, code) as runningtotal
        ,case when (select count(1) from test b where b.account = test.account and b.amount < 0) > 0 then 1 else 0 end as hasnegative
        ,ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by account order by case when amount < 0 then 0 else 1 end, code) as rownum
    from test
)
--select *  from cte 
,cte2 as (
    select 
        *
        ,max(rownum) over(partition by account ) as maxrownum 
        ,FIRST_VALUE(code) over(partition by account order by case when runningtotal > 0 then 0 else 1 end, code) as firstcode
        ,sum(case when amount < 0 then 1 else 0 end) over(partition by account) as negativecount
    from cte
)
--select * from cte2
select 
    --*,
    account as accountnumber
    ,case when hasnegative = 0 or negativecount = maxrownum then amount else runningtotal end as val
    ,case when hasnegative = 0 or negativecount = maxrownum then code else firstcode end as code

from cte2
where 
    runningtotal > 0 
    or rownum = maxrownum 
    or negativecount = maxrownum
order by account, code
```

Comment: I don't get it: how do you know which rows to net against? Eg account #7 has two rows in the desired result, but #3 only has one, and which value for `code` do you want?

Comment: @Charlieface Thanks for the response. I wasn't clear enough about that. If the negative value doesn't completely offset the first positive value, then those two should be netted together and leave the 3rd value alone. So for #7, codes A and C would be combined, but B would remain the same.

Comment: But why A and C, why not B and C?

Comment: C is negative and it should offset against the first positive value. Or if it's easier to add B and C that would be fine too really, but the existing (broken) process uses the first code.

Comment: Oh, and #3 only has one result because the negative amount completely removes everything from A and C. If that were left in code B that would be fine too, actually, that might be better.

Comment: @nickfinity please explain the whole logic in your question with samples otherwise you won't get the right answer

Comment: You might want to ponder using `min` and `max` of [`sign( amount )`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sign-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to summarize the positive/negative/zero status of the values.

Comment: @eshirvana I'll expand on the logic, but the desired output is shown.

Comment: @nickfinity I think I understand everything but "8". Why does this get condensed down to the single aggregate sum, when "7" has the two records with just the negative added to the first bucket. I don't see the pattern.

Comment: @Error_2646 That's a good question. The end result is a positive value, and the business doesn't want to show any negative records. I'll expand on the logic. I've been staring at this too long so the questions have been very helpful. I appreciate everyone looking at this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not sure , but this might be the answer you are looking for:

```
SELECT  account , SUM(amount) amount , min(code) code FROM (
SELECT *, dense_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY account , CASE WHEN amount> 0 THEN 1 ELSE -1 END ORDER BY code) rn2 FROM (
    SELECT account , SUM(amount) amount , min(code) code FROM (
        SELECT *, dense_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY account , CASE WHEN amount> 0 THEN 1 ELSE -1 END ORDER BY id) rn FROM test) tt
    GROUP BY account , rn
    HAVING SUM(amount) <> 0 
    ) tt2
) tt3
GROUP BY account , rn2
ORDER BY account
```

Comment: I'll dig in and do some additional testing, but this looks great so far. You're a life saver! I really appreciate the help.

Comment: @nickfinity you are welcome ,let me know , I'm just curious if it really worked for you!